# Python mechanism to load site-packages relative to program/script location?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pythonpath

For a set of programs written in most languages (C for instance) a script can normally run those programs without any sort of interference between dynamic link libraries and with no special hand holding so long as they are all found on PATH.  That is, the following will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
prog1
prog2
prog3
```

However, if these three programs are written in Python and they import conflicting package versions then to run each one successfully it must either be installed into a virtualenv or each must have a separate site-packages directory which is referenced by PYTHONPATH.  Either way they need a set up and possibly a tear down before running.  That is, for virtualenv:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $PROG1_ROOT/bin/activate
prog1
deactivate
source $PROG2_ROOT/bin/activate
prog2
deactivate
source $PROG3_ROOT/bin/activate
prog3
deactivate
```

and for separate site-packages:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=$PROG1_ROOT/lib/python3.6/site-packages
prog1
export PYTHONPATH=$PROG2_ROOT/lib/python3.6/site-packages
prog2
export PYTHONPATH=$PROG3_ROOT/lib/python3.6/site-packages
prog3
```

This problem results because

import pkg_resources

(at least through Python3.6) cannot reliably import the proper versions when multiple versions of a package share the same site-package directory, even if __requires__ precedes it listing all the version restrictions.

It occurs to me that if PYTHONPATH, or some equivalent, could be specified **relative to the program** instead of the $PWD, and some consistency in directory layout was observed, then it would only have to be set once.  That is, if prog1 is in $PROG1_ROOT/bin and its libraries are in $PROG1_ROOT/lib/python3.6/site-packages, then setting PYTHONPATH to "../lib/python3.6/site-packages" would work not only for prog1, but also for prog2, prog3, and for as many more as are needed through progN.

However, PYTHONPATH is normally provided as an absolute path, and relative paths are I believe with respect to $PWD, not to the python program (prog1).  Is there some other Python path variable which has the desired property?  Failing that, is there some type of file which could be dropped into $PROG1_ROOT/bin which would be normally picked up by a python program when it starts and which could direct it to use $PROG1_ROOT/lib/python3.6/site-packages?  It would be OK to have either the relative or absolute path in that file, although the former would still be preferred because then one could move the entire PROG1_ROOT directory tree to another location in the file system without having to rewrite this special file.  I really want to avoid solutions which would require modifying prog1 etc. themselves (ie, prog1 in the example).

Thanks.

EDITED:

I wrote this:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/python-devirtualizer/

to implement some of these ideas.  At this point it is Linux (or at least POSIX) specific.  It slightly modifies python scripts in a package's "bin" directory by changing the first line, and it "wraps" everything in that directory with a replacement native binary which injects a custom PYTHONPATH into the true target's environment.  That binary looks up its location using a function from libSDL2 and then specifies the PYTHONPATH relative to that.  So far it has worked pretty well, and the "programs" in installed python packages (the "bin" directory's contents) are run based on PATH just like any other program, no futzing about with PYTHONPATH in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Making search paths relative to the executable is a Very Bad Idea (TM). Move the executable or libraries around, all hell breaks loose. Some enterprising miscreant might notice the path settings and place a script just right to get their own doctored libraries (or just flawed old versions) to be used. And so on.

Clean up the misbehaving scripts. Chances are that by using old versions they are vulnerable to by now fixed security boo-boos, or other misbehaviours. Or find a way to load the stuff in the script itself.

Comment: Thought experiment - let every program in an OS be written in python and let many have conflicting package versions so that they cannot reside in a single site-package directory. They either need to be in virtualenv's or have specific PYTHONPATHs.  That system would be extremely unpleasant to use because one could never just execute a command. One would always have to possess special information, apply it, run the command, and sometimes deactivate afterwards.  "Cleaning up" that number of packages is not going to happen. So how to let "prog1" just run, always?